# Creating div element using jquery and adding inner html

Tags: jquery, html

Im making some div element dynamically

```
var QuickPanelItem = $('<div/>', { 'id': 'div' + WidgetDetails.Name + 'QuickPanel', 'class': 'left_slidethumbs button_' + WidgetDetails.Name + '' });            
QuickPanelItem.append($('<div/>', { 'class': 'text_button' }));
$("#divLeftQuickPanel").append(QuickPanelItem);
```

my doubt is

```
$('<div/>', { 'class': 'text_button' })
```

we can add attributes of the element by writting them in the flower brackets as in the above line, But how can we add background-image,margin,padding etc which comes under style property.
Also adding inner html.

Comment: `.css()`, `.html()` and so on.

Comment: $('element').css('margin','20px').css('padding','');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

**js**

```
$("<div/>",{
    id: "a",
    text:"sadsad",
    style:"background-color:red;height:50px;",
    class: "classA"
  }).appendTo("body");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZqY4/4/)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it the exact same way, as jQuery supports any jQuery method in the object passed when creating a new element

```
$('<div />', { 
    'class': 'text_button',
    css    : {
          backgroundImage : 'url(image.png)',
          margin : '10px 20px 3px 5px'

    },
    html   : '<p>CONTENT</p>',
    on     : {
         click : function() {
            alert();
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Each of the left-hand keys here also have corresponding getter/setter methods, which can be chained and used at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Use this **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

```
$('#div' + WidgetDetails.Name + 'QuickPanel').css({
    "background-image":"/path",
    "margin":"20px",
    "padding":"4px"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I know this way, but I need it in the format I specified in the question,